# Recover files from accidently formatted NTFS dd image by Magic Bytes?

Tags: dd, ntfs, forensics

I have an dd image of a partition that once had a Windows 10 NTFS filesystem and then got accidentally formatted (or so I assume) and now has a pretty empty NTFS with only an empty Windows directory on it.

Is it possible to recover at least some files by scanning the binary dump for Magic Bytes?

I tried testdisk, foremost and some other tools without finding *any* file so I'm wondering if NTFS somehow works that different than FAT or ext where the contents can be found even if the filesystem is not readable any more.

Comment: NTFS of course works slightly differently, but in the end, the data *has* to be on the disk somewhere, and especially small files are likely to be sequential. Try binwalk. good luck.

Comment: Of course, especially if this happened on an SSD, then "formatting" might just have told the SSD to discard all the data, so you `dd`'ed a lot of zeros. easy test: if this image `gzip`s to basically nothing, you can give up.

Comment: Discarding all data without explicitly overwriting them (which would take a long time) is possible on SSDs? Anyway, as I can find only random data at various offsets and even at the end of the image, I guess there must have been some kind of encryption at work.

Comment: Identifying and recovering files by their contents, or "Magic Bytes" would be the job of `testdisk`'s sister program: `PhotoRec`.

Comment: As @telcoM mentioned, you should use `photorec`. In `photorec` there are options for a) selecting ntfs as the underlying system and b) searching by magic bytes. you just need to run `photorec` as sudo. Unless you went through some serious effort actively erasing your partition, you will virtually always come up with something. I have formatted partitions, put new OSes on them, then re-filled them up 90% of the way ( per OS diskspace managers) and could still pull out files from when the previous OS was on them.  Even if `photorec` comes up empty, your data may still be recoverable.

Comment: "Discarding all data without explicitly overwriting them (which would take a long time) is possible on SSDs?" -- Yes. It's TRIM and it's [different than writing zeros](https://superuser.com/a/1242057/432690).